# Are HTML child nodes always contained within the Parent node?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

can it be possible that a HTML child node element has a bounding rectangle that does not lie completely inside it's parent node's bounding rectangle when displayed on the browser?

My use case is that, i am writing a program that allows the user to draw a rectangle on the browser and all the elements that lie within the rectangle should be hidden (by applying visibility: hidden css)

To do this I am performing a DFS on the DOM tree and stopping exploring the child nodes when I find an element that lies completely within the box the user has drawn. I am making the assumption that if I hide this element, I don't have to bother about exploring and hiding any of  it's descendants.

Comment: Yes, it's possible to place a child even completely outside of its parent by using absolute position. But, if you'll hide the parent, the children will also be hidden, because pulling an element out of the textflow, doesn't change the DOM tree structure.

Comment: In your use case, you have to worry about making the descendants visible. If they are not bound by their parent’s bounding box, they might be wrongly hidden.

Comment: You can also change the flow of the document elements by using CSS Grid.

Comment: A child can also be placed outside of its parent even if positioned relatively - for example with a margin setting.